# String Empty To Null - Empty Form Fields to null - Spring Editor - StringTrimmerEditor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, property-editor

I have read few posts, and tried implementing the same way, but somehow i am getting below error. I want to implement through `XML based configuration`.

Two Ways

**Annotation Based - Works Fine**

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Controller
public class AppBindingInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }

}
```

**XML Based - Getting Error**

```
<bean id="coreCustomEditors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
     <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="java.lang.String">
                <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor">
                    <constructor-arg name="emptyAsNull" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'customEditors'; nested exc
eption is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEditor
s[java.lang.String]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor] to required type [java.lang.Class] for property 'customEdito
rs[java.lang.String]': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor]
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:263)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedMap(TypeConverterDelegate.java:623)
        at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a class name as value, not a bean (as stated by the message), like this:

```
<bean id="coreCustomEditors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
     <property name="customEditors">
         <map>
             <entry key="java.lang.String" value="your.package.EmptyAsNullStringTrimmerEditor"/>
         </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

with `EmptyAsNullStringTrimmerEditor` being:

```
package your.package;

public class EmptyAsNullStringTrimmerEditor extends StringTrimmerEditor {
    public YourClass() { super(true); }
}
```

see [`CustomEditorConfigurer` javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/CustomEditorConfigurer.html)

Comment: how to pass `<constructor-arg name="emptyAsNull" value="true" />`

Comment: In 2nd option how does it identify which editor for which type of datatype, unlike in first option we provide `key as java.lanag.String' and values as its editor

Comment: Sorry I misread the doc, you have to subclass here, see my edit

Comment: i tried with you approach, made all possible changes, adding depends on etc, but seems like doing through xml, it is not even registering my beans. but if i follow my first approach seems tpo work fine.